Using islands and gaps to find slots that leave other staff slots open
We need to build a scheduling mechanism multiple several reps in a store that make phone calls. However, at least one rep must remain available at all times so that if there is a walk in they can give service to that customer. I have a table of open timeslots called tbl_timeslots with columns staffid, from_date, to_date and isopen.
I believe the following code works if all timeslots are of equal length. However, because when searching for an available timeslot, we need to make sure that there are other available timeslots of other staff, and these may be smaller or larger than the available staff and may also be made up of different staff, we actually need to find for each open timeslot if there is an "island" of other slots and not just one slot of a different staff.
I have come up with the following statement:
WITH all_slots AS 
(
    SELECT 
        slotid,
        from_date,
        to_date,
        staffid
    FROM 
        tbl_timeslots
    WHERE 
        isopen = 1
),
slot_boundaries AS 
(
    SELECT from_date AS date, staffid, 1 AS is_start
    FROM all_slots
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date AS date, staffid, -1 AS is_start
    FROM all_slots
),
island_formation AS 
(
    SELECT 
        date,
        staffid,
        SUM(is_start) OVER (PARTITION BY staffid ORDER BY date) AS open_count,
        SUM(is_start) OVER (PARTITION BY staffid ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_open_count
    FROM 
        slot_boundaries
),
islands AS 
(
    SELECT
        staffid,
        date AS start_date,
        LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY staffid ORDER BY date) AS end_date
    FROM 
        island_formation
    WHERE 
        prev_open_count = 0 AND open_count > 0
),
covered_slots AS 
(
    SELECT 
        x.slotid AS x_slotid,
        x.from_date AS x_from,
        x.to_date AS x_to,
        x.staffid AS x_staffid,
        i.staffid AS island_staffid,
        i.start_date AS island_start,
        i.end_date AS island_end
    FROM 
        all_slots x
    JOIN 
        islands i ON x.staffid != i.staffid 
                  AND i.start_date <= x.from_date 
                  AND (i.end_date >= x.to_date OR i.end_date IS NULL)
),
final_results AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        x_slotid,
        x_from,
        x_to,
        x_staffid,
        MIN(island_start) OVER (PARTITION BY x_slotid) AS island_start,
        MAX(island_end) OVER (PARTITION BY x_slotid) AS island_end
    FROM 
        covered_slots
)
SELECT * 
FROM final_results
WHERE island_start <= x_from 
  AND (island_end >= x_to OR island_end IS NULL)
ORDER BY x_from, x_to;

Sample schema and data:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_timeslots](
    [slotid] [int] NULL,
    [staffid] [int] NULL,
    [from_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [to_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [isopen] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(N'2024-01-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (3, 1, CAST(N'2024-01-01T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T14:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (5, 1, CAST(N'2024-01-01T14:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T15:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (6, 2, CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (7, 2, CAST(N'2024-01-01T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T13:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (8, 2, CAST(N'2024-01-01T13:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T14:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (9, 2, CAST(N'2024-01-01T14:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T15:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (10, 3, CAST(N'2024-01-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (11, 3, CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T17:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (14, 4, CAST(N'2024-01-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (15, 4, CAST(N'2024-01-01T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_timeslots] ([slotid], [staffid], [from_date], [to_date], [isopen]) VALUES (16, 4, CAST(N'2024-01-01T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2024-01-01T13:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)

However this does not work when the lengths of the timeslots are different.

Consumable sample data, and expected results, and details of what the results you are getting are what you want, will really help us help you here.

Show this does not work - where?

As far as "lengths of timeslots are different", can you break each timeslot down to the smallest quantum you want to represent? Like, if you have a slot of 30m, you'd break that down into 30 one minute slots.

The results from your current example don't make any sense. What does each row in tbl_timeslots represent? Your sample data only has "Open" intervals. Do we assume any interval not listed is "Closed"? What is your definition of an Island here? What should you final results represent? These would be good questions to answer, along with the info Thom A suggested.

@digital.aarion Each row is one timeslot which can be open or closed. Appointments can only be made on open timeslots. The sample data has open timeslots on purpose to initially check results that return all other timeslots. An island is considered for each timeslot X with staffid Y a period made up of timeslots that are open with staffids that are NOT Y and that their startperiod to end period collectively cover the period of X

I think I understand what you were trying to accomplish with slot_boundaries CTE, but I was not able to make sense of the logic after that.
I believe you are attempting to define a series of consecutive non-overlapping time intervals covering all of the schedules shifts (slots), such that every shift starts and ends on interval boundaries. From there you appear to be trying to calculate coverage for each interval in order to identify any uncovered intervals.
While this appears to be some variation on the gaps and islands problem, I do not believe this can be handled using typical gaps and islands logic, because of the irregular overlapping of slots. Given shifts of 10:00-14:00, 11:00-12:00, and 13:00-16:00, the overlap test using LAG()-based logic might cause a false gap detection between 12:00 and 13:00.
For problems like this, my preferred solution is to:

Identify all of the distinct start/end times involved. If desired, fixed start/end times may also be included.
Define consecutive, non-overlapping time intervals between each pair of ascending times.
Left-join those time intervals back to the original data.
Calculate the resulting coverage from the joined data.
(Optional) Consolidate consecutive intervals having the same coverage.

For your supplied schema, the following may be a start:'
DECLARE @ShiftStart datetime = '2024-01-01 08:00'
DECLARE @ShiftEnd datetime   = '2024-01-01 22:00'

;WITH slot_boundaries AS 
(
    -- Get distinct boundary times of interest
    -- (UNION without ALL is implicitly DISTINCT)
    SELECT from_date AS date
    FROM tbl_timeslots
    UNION
    SELECT to_date AS date
    FROM tbl_timeslots
    UNION
    SELECT @ShiftStart
    UNION
    SELECT @ShiftEnd
),
slots AS
(
    -- Define time intervals between each ascending time boundary
    -- (Final row will be excluded later)
    SELECT 
        date AS start_date,
        LEAD(date) OVER(ORDER BY date) AS end_date
    FROM slot_boundaries
),
slot_coverage AS 
(
    -- Calculate coverage
    SELECT
        i.start_date,
        i.end_date,
        COUNT(x.slotid) AS OpenCoverage,
        STRING_AGG(x.staffid, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY x.staffid) AS OpenStaff
    FROM slots i
    LEFT JOIN tbl_timeslots x
        ON x.from_date <= i.start_date 
        AND x.to_date >= i.end_date
        AND x.isopen = 1
    WHERE i.end_date IS NOT NULL -- Exclude final unbounded row
    GROUP BY i.start_date, i.end_date
)
SELECT *
FROM slot_coverage
-- WHERE OpenCoverage = 0
ORDER BY start_date

Note that I included fixed @ShiftStart and @ShiftEnd values and moved the isopen = 1 check down into the slot_coverage CTE. I was unable to understand the purpose of the x.staffid != i.staffid check in your original code, so that is not included in the above logic.
Hopefully, you can make any necessary adjustments to suit your needs. This might also include logic to partition the data by date and ignoring times when the store is closed.
Sample results:



start_date
end_date
OpenCoverage
OpenStaff




2024-01-01 08:00
2024-01-01 10:00
0
null


2024-01-01 10:00
2024-01-01 11:00
3
1,3,4


2024-01-01 11:00
2024-01-01 12:00
4
1,2,3,4


2024-01-01 12:00
2024-01-01 13:00
4
1,2,3,4


2024-01-01 13:00
2024-01-01 14:00
3
1,2,3


2024-01-01 14:00
2024-01-01 15:00
3
1,2,3


2024-01-01 15:00
2024-01-01 17:00
1
3


2024-01-01 17:00
2024-01-01 22:00
0
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Assume we need to find all 2 hour open spots for a phone appointment. This can be used with a simple select statement. But now we need to make sure that if for all such slots X, there will remain one or more slots (but NOT with X's staffid), that together will form an island that cover X's period so that if there is a walkin to the store there will always be someone to serve them. The slots that form the island  can be one slot or many, and they can overlap, as long as they do not have X's staffid because X will be on the call at the time and can not meet the walkin customer.

If you have additional requirements, it is best to add them to the question. Make sure you include a clear explanation, appropriate sample data covering the various scenarios, expected results, and your attempt at solving the problem. Since this seems to go beyond the original statement (there is no mention of "find all 2 hour open spots"), you might need to start over with a separate question. Make sure that your question is complete and clear and include all of the requested elements.

The 2 hour open spots is just a specific example. To simplify, the original question assumes that all timeslots are open . So for each such open timeslot X, the question is how can we make sure that there is an island of timeslots of OTHER staff, that covers the length of X)

"If you have additional requirements, it is best to add them to the question." ...
